# Does syncing iphone to a new computer erases notes linked to the gmail account?

Tags: iphone, itunes, gmail, notes.app

I have an iPhone with a bunch of items in the notes app I don't want to loose.
The notes are linked to a gmail account.
I want to switch iTunes library for that iPhone. Going from a PC to a mac.
iTunes wants to do an "erase and sync". Will that erase my notes as well? Or just the music?

Answer (score 1):

The erase and sync function is only for items synced from the previous computer in regards to media.
Outlook would have been the only application on a PC that would sync your notes.
So if you haven't used outlook on your PC, then you should be fine to erase and sync. 
Also, if they are through your gmail account this will be unaffected even if they are erased, because by signing into the gmail account it will sync the notes over the air which is separate from any syncing with a computer.
Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure all the notes are on the gmail account:

1. In iPhone, press "< Folders" in top-left corner of the main screen in Notes app and ensure all your notes are under gmail and not "On this Phone". If you have notes only "On this Phone", you will need to manually copy them, email them, or use a program like iExplorer to extract them to .txt files.
2. go to gmail on the web and view the Notes label, you should see all your notes there.

Then, go ahead and erase and sync all you want, the notes are stored in Gmail and will be restored to any iphone as long as you add the gmail account back to the phone and check to sync "Notes" under Settings/Mail/your gmail account.

If you don't see them, go to "< Folders" again and select the Gmail folder.

Also, select the default account under Settings/Notes if you want new notes to go to gmail again.